# GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), despite compiling successfully.(vuejs+django webapp)

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, webpack, webpack.config.js

I am working on the cutecats tutorial and have trouble while integrating vue+django. I get no errors on compilation, the bundle.js is created and I can see it in my IDE, but the bundle returns a 404 error on browser.

Here is the tutorial that I have followed - https://medium.com/@jrmybrcf/how-to-build-api-rest-project-with-django-vuejs-part-i-228cbed4ce0c

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
var WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: 'webpack-stats.json'}),
    new WriteFilePlugin()
    ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

I am getting an error - index:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Webpack conf has nothing to do with this error. Show Django settings part for static files and static files folder structure. Did you copy bundle files to django static folder after compilation?

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial, the public path is set to be `STATIC_URL = '/public/'`.

Try to open http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/bundle.js instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/dist/bundle.js.

If it works, change `publicPath` from `'/dist/'` to `'/public/'`